# Why @ is added before the package name in ansible

Tags: linux, ansible, yaml

i would ask you why it was added `@` before `Development tools` and what is the purpose from it. I know that's used to include
all of the parameters passed to the package.

```
- name: Install the 'Development tools' package group
  ansible.builtin.yum:
    name: "@Development tools"
    state: present
```

Comment: RTFM - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html. this exact example is listed in the docs. `Package groups are specified as “@development-tools” and environment groups are “@^gnome-desktop-environment”. Use the “yum group list hidden ids” command to see which category of group the group you want to install falls into.`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle thank you for the reply but my question is what's the purpose of the '@'

Comment: As I said, the documentation covers this with your exact use case. `Yum itself has two types of groups. “Package groups” are specified in the rpm itself while “environment groups” are specified in a separate file (usually by the distribution). Unfortunately, this division becomes apparent to ansible users because ansible needs to operate on the group of packages in a single transaction and yum requires groups to be specified in different ways when used in that way.`. I kinda figured you would go look at the documentation after I gave you the direct link to it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it makes sense. Your explanation was clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why @ is added before the package name in ansible

Because it's not a package, it's a group.

> what's the purpose of the '@'

To differentiate between package names and package groups.

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  Which is exactly what Chris Doyle already tried to explain to the OP an hour ago :(